# VS2008 C++ Header and Class Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2008

We using a mixture of C++ (MFC) and C# within our software, and include the usual copyright spiel above our classes and wish to include it automatically.

I've updated my C# Class Template file in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class.zip

Question is does anyone know how to do the same for MFC .cpp and .h files?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Source code templates are located in subdirectories of VC\VCWizards\AppWiz\MFC.  Look in Application\templates\xxxx*.cpp for example; xxxx is your locale ID (1033 = USA).